# Vertical alignment of 3 side by side subfigures

Tags: vertical-alignment, subfloats

I have read previous answers on this exact topic but nothing seems to work with my code.

At the moment I have:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height = 10cm]{image1.jpg}
        \caption{}
        \label{left}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \enskip
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height = 10cm]{image2.jpg}
        \caption{}
        \label{right}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \enskip
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
       \centering
       \includegraphics[height = 7 cm, width = \textwidth]{image3.jpg}
       \label{legend here}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{}
    \label{xraydataofdiclofenacCAGE}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

but I get the images like this:

[image]

where the last picture is a picture of the legend that I nabbed off of someone with some extra data. At the moment the other two appear to be aligning fine but the third one is not aligning from the top as I would like it to.

Any help and I would be very grateful

Comment: If I add the `demo` option to the `graphicx` package (because I don't have your image files available)  and if I add the `subcaption` package to the preamble (otherwise the `subfigure` environment is undefined), I get the following output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnvXr.png

Comment: If I additionally add `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` to the preamble and add `valign=t` to each of the `\includegraphics` commands, I get the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7cQk.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've well understood your problem, you have the `[T]`  alignment option for `subfigure`:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[T]{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height = 10cm]{image1.jpg}
        \caption{}
        \label{left}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \enskip
    \begin{subfigure}[T]{0.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height = 10cm]{image2.jpg}
        \caption{}
        \label{right}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \enskip
    \begin{subfigure}[T]{0.25\textwidth}
       \centering
       \includegraphics[height = 7 cm, width = \textwidth]{image3.jpg}
      \caption{} \label{legend here}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{}
    \label{xraydataofdiclofenacCAGE}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: so my problem was in using a lower case t - Ive used an upper case T to good effect - thank you for helping solve this problem

Comment: There are other solutions, e.g. with package `adjustbox` or with `floatrow`. For me, this is the simplest way to go..B. t. w., you should read carefully the packages documentations.